# why does client.get_all_members return None?

Tags: python, discord.py

Ive tried:

```py
@client.command()
async def id(message, name):
    discriminlist = str(name).split('#')
    p = client.get_all_members()
    found_members = filter(lambda m: m.discriminator==discriminlist[0], p)
    member = discord.utils.get(found_members, name=discriminlist[1])
    id = member.id
    await message.channel.send(id)
```

and got:

```
Ignoring exception in command id:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 49, in id
    id = member.id
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id
```

What I'm trying to do is make a discord bot command that allows you to get the ID of a user so you can use the ID in commands instead of mentioning them eg. my friend GlowNinja is sleeping due to timezones its night for him when its day for me and I want to give him money in the discord bot but I don't want to mention him and wake him up (he has his notifs on for some reason) so I want to send the id instead of the mention but when I do this I get errors and I don't get an ID

Answer (score 1):

First off, you might not want to define the function as `id()`, since that is already a built-in Python function. (You can still make the command named *id* by passing `name="id"` to the decorator, i.e. `@client.command(name="id")`.

Second, it is `discord.utils.get()` which is returning `None`, not `client.get_all_members()`. You are trying to search for a member by their name, but you are passing a discriminator to the function. Usernames are formatted `Username#1234`; splitting at `"#'` and taking the character at index 1 will return `1234`, the discriminator.

In fact, most of the code in your function is unnecessary. You can access all the members of the guild with `ctx.guild.members`, so you can just pass that and the name of the member to search to `discord.utils.get()` directly, using neither the `client.get_all_members()` function nor the `filter()` function.

```py
@client.command(name="id")
async def get_id(ctx, name):
    username, discriminator = name.split("#")
    member = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, name=username)
    await ctx.channel.send(member.id)
```

*On a side note, while functionality is not affected, you probably want the first argument of the function to be `ctx`, not `message`, since the argument passed is a `Context` object, not a `Message` object.*